# sequence of series approximating another series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $c$ be a converging infinite series, $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of converging infinite series. $a_{n}$ have the property that the first $n$ terms of $c-a_{n}$ vanish. Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}c-a_{n}=0$?

This should be easy to prove, but I can't show that $c-a_{n}$ goes to zero. I try defining the supremum $M_{n}$ of $c-a_{n}$ and try to show that the $M_{n}$ goes to zero but it doesn't seem working. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that each $a_n$ is a series. If so, which concept of convergence are you using?

Comment: yes, the series converge in norm, so just usual convergence.

Comment: And which norm is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $c=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}0$ and $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}0+\sum_{i=n}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^{i-n}}$. Then $c$ and $a_n$ have the same first $n$ terms but $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}c-a_n=0-2=-2\neq 0.$$